# Embedded mongodb to spring-boot application java exception

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I need to set embedded mongodb in my springboot project but it show infinite error logs. Someone can help me?
I use these dependencies

```html
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.flapdoodle.embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cz.jirutka.spring/embedmongo-spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-E from Project-B -->
                    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And then i configure the mongoTemplate with this method in a configuration class

```html
     private static final String MONGO_DB_URL = "localhost";
        private static final String MONGO_DB_NAME = "embedded_db";

        @Bean
        public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
            EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean mongo = new EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean();
            mongo.setBindIp(MONGO_DB_URL);
            MongoClient mongoClient = (MongoClient) mongo.getObject();
            return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, MONGO_DB_NAME);
        }
```

But when i run my application it show this error+

```html
Exception in thread "main" 11:56:00.710 [Thread-0] DEBUG de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.CachingArtifactStore - force delete for PRODUCTION:Windows:B64 and de.flapdoodle.embed.process.extract.ImmutableExtractedFileSet@545997b1
11:56:00.710 [Thread-1] DEBUG de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess - try to stop mongod
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.<init>(com.mongodb.connection.Cluster, java.util.List, java.lang.Object)'
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:319)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:291)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:286)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:282)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:180)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:145)
    at cz.jirutka.spring.embedmongo.EmbeddedMongoBuilder.build(EmbeddedMongoBuilder.java:104)
    at cz.jirutka.spring.embedmongo.EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean.getObject(EmbeddedMongoFactoryBean.java:52)
    at com.nextage.arcacrmconnector.commons.EmbeddedMongoDb.mongoTemplate(EmbeddedMongoDb.java:20)
    at com.nextage.arcacrmconnector.commons.MongoTemplateSingleton.setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplateSingleton.java:20)
    at com.nextage.arcacrmconnector.commons.MongoTemplateSingleton.getMongoTemplate(MongoTemplateSingleton.java:13)
    at com.nextage.arcacrmconnector.services.CommonMongoService.<init>(CommonMongoService.java:12)
    at com.nextage.arcacrmconnector.services.LogService.<init>(LogService.java:18)
    at com.nextage.arcacrmconnector.consumer.QueueConsumerTimerTask.<init>(QueueConsumerTimerTask.java:23)
    at com.nextage.arcacrmconnector.application.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:30)
11:56:00.716 [Thread-0] WARN de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.file.Files - could not delete C:\Users\DONATE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\extract-70ac2cd1-bb5b-4276-9243-cdf6b52db3famongod.exe. Will try to delete it again when program exits.
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.base/java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:213)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.file.FileCleaner.forceDeleteOnExit(FileCleaner.java:51)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.file.Files.forceDelete(Files.java:128)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.extract.ExtractedFileSets.delete(ExtractedFileSets.java:77)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ArtifactStore.removeFileSet(ArtifactStore.java:90)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.CachingArtifactStore$FilesWithCounter.forceDelete(CachingArtifactStore.java:176)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.CachingArtifactStore.removeAll(CachingArtifactStore.java:100)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.CachingArtifactStore$CacheCleaner.run(CachingArtifactStore.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

How can i fix it? It is a dependency version error?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String tempFile = System.getenv("temp") + File.separator + "extract-" + System.getenv("USERNAME") + "-extractmongod";
    String executable;
    if (System.getenv("OS") != null && System.getenv("OS").contains("Windows")) {
        executable = tempFile + ".exe";
    } else {
        executable = tempFile + ".sh";
    }
    Files.deleteIfExists(new File(executable).toPath());
    Files.deleteIfExists(new File(tempFile + ".pid").toPath());


please try this temporary solution. write this in mongo config file,This should be executed before the start of embedded mongo db

link is : https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/171
```